# Free Trial Subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

I have an application that has 6 subscriptions (3 with monthly billing (A, B, C) and 3 with semi-annually billing (X, Y, Z)). I have configured the free trial of 3 days and I have not activated "Activate subscription-level free trial" on google play console.
[image]

However, if a user enrolls in a monthly billing subscription, even after the expiration of free trial the user is still provided with a free trial for the semi-annually billing subscription.

For example, A user enrolls in "A subscription" and after the expiration of free trial i.e. 3 days the user can enroll in X, Y or Z plan for free but not on B and C. My requirement is after using free trial for one subscription, the user shouldn't be provided with free trial anymore.

Comment: According to documentation/play console- Subscription level free trial- Allow your users to sign up for a free trial for each available subscription within your app. Otherwise, the user can sign up to only one free trial within your app

Comment: Have you provides the free trial of 3 days for all the subscriptions while setting ""Activate subscription-level free trial" to off?